# One random sample Mean or 30 Random samples Mean

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, sample, stratification

I have 30m records and i want to do a random stratified sample to estimate the mean based on predefined strata.
Should i estimate the mean while taking 1 random (n=500) sample or to sample lets say 30 different stratified random samples (each n=500), calculate samples mean and than estimate the overall mean ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in the empirical distribution of sample mean? Even if the empirical distribution is not your concern, the second approach will still give you a more robust result as the LLN guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the concentration of the attribute of interest in select strata, and knowledge of the weight of each strata in the parent population, stratified random sampling may provide an improved estimate of the population mean for a select attribute. See sources and [references here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185229/when-should-you-choose-stratified-sampling-over-random-sampling) to the question "When should you choose stratified sampling over random sampling", and in particular, comments by Chris C, as well as my prior [comments here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489982/concept-impact-of-random-sampling-on-the-uncertainty-associated-with-making-inf/490021#490021), maybe informative.

Of possible additional interest is how to compute the total required sample size for a specified level of precision and its corresponding allocation across strata for a stratified random sampling scheme. Here is an illustrated example, [presented here](http://www.uky.edu/%7Ejmlhot2/Resources/Calculating%20Sample%20Size%20for%20Stratified%20Random%20Sample.pdf) that may prove useful.